# How to reset a Dell PC with Windows XP back to factory settings?

Tags: windows-xp, restore, factory-defaults

How do I restore my Windows XP Dell PC to factory settings? I have already tried `F2` and `F12`. If you can help thanks.

Comment: Try pressing "the CTRL and F11 keys simultaneously when you see the Dell logo after turning on the laptop." http://en.kioskea.net/faq/7319-dell-inspiron-restore-to-factory-default-settings#for-windows-xp

Comment: This link echos what screener has said http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3524/t/19297896.aspx  also "After the Dell splash screen you should see a blue bar at top of screen. If you do, it is a good sign
that the DSR partition is still working. If you don't see it, it might be removed and you can't do
a restore.
Pressing the     Control Key and F11     needs to be done during the time the blue bar is on the screen
which is about 2 seconds."

Comment: @Ramhound You wrote "The simplest way is to use an installation disk and install Windows XP over the current installation. "  <-- No. Never in a million years is what you suggested going to restore it to factory settings, which is what he asked. You'd have a better suggestion than you did, if you said to remove the windows installation on there and install one fresh, (which may be what you meant while saying differently) though even that wouldn't be answering his question.

Comment: @Ramhound No and No. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14747/barlop-ramhound-installing-windows-xp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14748/discussion-between-barlop-and-ramhound).

Comment: You don't have to join it. The reason why I opened it was to correct your comment, without making the comments section too long. You don't have to post a comment saying that you won't discuss or that saying that you won't post a comment. The whole point of me creating the chat was to make the comments less messy. So if you don't want to discuss this in chat, or you're not able to, then don't comment saying you don't want to discuss it, simply don't. Otherwise it litters the comments, causing deletions.

Answer (score 1):

1) SAVE YOUR PERSONAL DATA !!! BEFORE YOU ENTER RECOVERY

2)
a.   Turn on the computer.

b.   When the Dell splash screen appears during the computer startup process, press and hold Ctrl and then press F11. Then, release both keys at the same time.

c.   In the Dell PC Restore by Symantec window, click Restore. Alternatively, press Tab to highlight Restore, and then press Enter.

d.   When a warning message appears stating that all data will be lost, click Confirm, or press Tab to highlight Confirm and then press Enter.

The Progress window will appear. Once the restore process starts, Dell PC Restore by Symantec usually takes about 8 to 10 minutes to finish.

When the restore process is complete, the following message will appear:
The system recovery process was successful.

e.   Click Finish or press Tab to highlight Finish and then press Enter to restart the computer.The software is now installed as it was when the computer was first received.

3) Backup your personal data

http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/bb/en/bbbsdt1/KCS/KcsArticles/ArticleIframeView?docid=DSN_181316&doclang=EN#Issue5

Comment: Look at Step 2b. For some reason you managed to miss out the keys he is meant to press

Comment: You should include the link you got it from e.g. http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/us/en/04/KCS/KcsArticles/ArticleIframeView?docid=DSN_181316&doclang=EN#Issue5  or in your case somewhere else

Answer (score -1):

This [Yahoo Answers](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110717071423AA3a7pX) link mentions the Restore method along with supporting Dell links.

I've included for Windows 7 and Vista as well as for Windows XP

Scroll down this answer for Windows XP

http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/kcs/document?c=us&l=en&s=gen&docid=DSN_362066&isLegacy=true

## Dell Factory Reset Instructions:

> ```
> Windows 7 PC Restore 
> 1. Turn on or reboot/restart the computer. 
> 2. As the computer starts, press <F8> on the keyboard until the Advanced Boot Options menu appears on the screen. 
> 3. Press the <Down Arrow> on the keyboard to select Repair Your Computer on the Advanced Boot Options menu, and then press <Enter>. 
> 4. Specify the language settings that you want, and then click Next. 
> 5. Log in as a user who has administrative credentials, and then click OK. 
> 6. Click Dell Factory Image Restore. 
> 7. In the Dell Factory Image Restore window, click Next. 
> 8. Click to select the Yes, reformat hard drive and restore system software to factory condition check box. 
> 9. Click Next and the computer will be restored to the default factory configuration. 
> 10. When the restore operation is completed, click Finish to restart the computer.
> ```
>
> - F12 to select boot device <-- yahoo answer says/adds

---

http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/kcs/document?c=us&l=en&s=gen&docid=DSN_336966&isLegacy=true

```
PC Restore for Windows Vista 
1. Turn on or reboot/restart the computer. 
2. As the computer starts, press <F8> on the keyboard until the Advanced Boot Options menu appears on the screen. 
3. Press the <Down Arrow> on the keyboard to select Repair Your Computer on the Advanced Boot Options menu, and then press <Enter>. 
4. Specify the language settings that you want, and then click Next. 
5. Log in as a user who has administrative credentials, and then click OK. 
6. Click Dell Factory Image Restore. 
7. In the Dell Factory Image Restore window, click Next. 
8. Click to select the Yes, reformat hard drive and restore system software to factory condition check box. 
9. Click Next and the computer will be restored to the default factory configuration. 
10. When the restore operation is completed, click Finish to restart the computer. 
Dell link for Vista
```

---

http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/us/en/04/KCS/KcsArticles/ArticleView?c=us&l=en&s=gen&docid=DSN_181316

```
PC Restore for Windows XP 
1. Turn on or reboot/restart the computer. 
2. When the Dell splash screen appears during the computer startup process, press and hold <Ctrl> and then press <F11>. Then, release both keys at the same time. 
3. In the Dell PC Restore by Symantec window, click Restore. Alternatively, press <Tab> to highlight Restore, and then press <Enter>. 
4. When a warning message appears stating that all data will be lost, click Confirm, or press <Tab> to highlight Confirm and then press <Enter>. 
The Progress window will appear. Once the restore process starts, Dell PC Restore by Symantec usually takes about 8 to 10 minutes to finish. 
5. Click Finish or press <Tab> to highlight Finish and then press <Enter> to restart the computer.
```